# Harmonic mean and Quadratic mean in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column with data in my DB I need find some mathematical operations (means) for.
For arithmetic mean SQL has aggregate functions AVG(), for geometric mean I can use the following

```
select exp(sum(ln(column)) / count(*)) from data_table
```

or this query

```
select exp(avg(ln(column))) from data_table
```

but I also need harmonic mean and quadratic mean. How can I do it in MySQL? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per for the formula(s) from wiki

[For harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean)

[image]

You could use `count(*)/sum(1/col)` expression

[For quadratic mean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadratic_mean)

[image]

You could use `sqrt(sum(col * col)/count(*))`

```
select 
count(*)/sum(1/col) harmonic_mean,
sqrt(sum(col * col)/count(*)) quadratic_mean
from table1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0f326/5)

Answer (score 2):

[Harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/SUM(1/column_value) FROM data_table;
```

[Quadratic mean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadratic_mean)

```
SELECT SQRT(SUM(column_value*column_value)/COUNT(*)) FROM data_table;
```